User authenticated with federated Google Sign In with Firebase has null email using Credential Manager in Android
I'm implementing the new fancy, shiny Credential Manager in my app using Jetpack Compose Material3. I'm building the credential request as per docs.
The sign in is successful, however, the user has email as null (when I access the property) and the email is not verified. In console I see a dash:  when it comes to identifier (I suppose here should have been the email?).
Any clues as to why my app is not able to fetch the credential information of a user after sign in?
I've exhausted all links on the web with regards to this issue (most are older and deal with a different sign in library).

Debugging
I tried printing the user I get from signing in with google (AuthResult returned value), the email and whether it has email verified as well as additionalUserInfo profile and providerId and I get (I've redacted out information):
D  user: com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzaf@86c120f // email: null // isEmailVerified: false // username: null // profile: {given_name={{FIRST_NAME}}, family_name={{LAST_NAME}}, picture=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/..., aud=#.apps.googleusercontent.com, azp=#.apps.googleusercontent.com, exp=#, iat=#, iss=https://accounts.google.com, sub=#, name={{FULL_NAME}}, nonce=d8c25bb...} // providerId: google.com

So definitely the user gets created (as I can see it in Firebase Auth console), though it seems it's of empty data?

Tested with a different Google account and with that one it works. I think it's my main Google account settings that's preventing data to be used by firebase auth.

Checked my main Google account settings. Everything is fine. Most probably this happens because my firebase admin account is the same as my main Google account with which I'm trying to sign in to my app. Probably firebase detects they're the same and in order not to lock me out overrides the auth user from app sign in. Can't think of another explanation.

I'm getting the same behavior. I'm so happy I found your question here. I started to think I was the only one with this sh&%#. Have you found the reason why and/or a way to fix it?

Yes. Google Support gave me a script with which to create a user (email and password) and then transition it to federated. Doing these steps in this specific sequence will have the account working for federated sign in.

Thank you, @Alexandru! How can I contact Google Support? I found a few options, but none seem to be what I need. Would you mind sharing the solution as an answer to your question? This would be a lifesaver for me! Thank you so much!

Basically, running this command: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user . It'll create an email & password user, though, signing in with Google will override provider and have the login succeed

Running this command: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user will solve the issue. It'll create an email & password user, though, signing in with Google will override provider and have the login succeed.
